# Entity Framework multi table query

Tags: linq, entity-framework, lambda

I need guidance with what I think is a complex Entity Framework 4.1 table query.

[image]

An item has a list of associated Identities.  A user then has a list of Identities that can be selected.  So I'd like to only return items that have identities that are in the user's list and are selected.  Any suggestions on how to best tackle this?  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
var results = db.UserIdentities
                .Where( x => x.UserId == someUserId && x.Selected)
                .Select( x => x.Identity.Item);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I think that may work, I'm testing it out.  var results = db.UserIdentities
                .Where( x => x.UserId == someUserId && x.Selected)
                .SelectMany( x => x.Identity.Item);

Comment: @NullReference: If I understood your setup correctly you shouldn't need `SelectMany()` - isn't there a 1:1 relationship between UserIdentity and Identity, and also a 1:1 relationship between Identity and Item ?

Comment: There is a *:1 relationship between UserIdentity and Identity and  Identity and Item.  The model is still not 100% perfect and I'm still learning about EF. Thanks again for the help at least it got me on the right track.